# Check for skipped index in array if the value was incremented by more than 1

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on an application which has meal delivery service. It checks for the meal which the user has already taken and allows user to choose a meal depending on the time.

But if the user skips the meals in between it should get logged in the skipped section so the user also allotted those skipped meals.

e.g. if already taken meal is 'morning' and user skips directly to 'night', they should also get 'afternoon', 'evening' meals.

Here's what I already have and it's giving me the desired output. But want to see if it can be done a better way or optimised way.

```
const meals = ['morning', 'afternoon', 'evening', 'night', 'midnight'];

const currentMeal = 'afternoon';
const navigatedMeal = 'midnight';

const skippedMealsBy = meals.indexOf(navigatedMeal) - meals.indexOf(currentMeal);

if(skippedMealsBy > 1) {
    const navigatedMealIndex = meals.indexOf(navigatedMeal);
    const currentMealIndex = meals.indexOf(currentMeal) + 1;

    const skippedMealsArray = [];
    for(var i=currentMealIndex; i<=navigatedMealIndex; i++) {
        skippedMealsArray.push(meals[i]);
    }
}

Expected output: ['evening', 'night', 'midnight'];
```

Comment: From a time complexity perspective, this can't be improved but you can use `Array.prototype.slice` instead of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is slice the array from the two indicies.

```js
const meals = ['morning', 'afternoon', 'evening', 'night', 'midnight'];

const currentMeal = 'afternoon';
const navigatedMeal = 'midnight';

const result = meals.slice(
  // add 1 so the currentMeal isn't included
  meals.indexOf(currentMeal) + 1,
  // add 1 because `.slice` excludes the final index in the result
  meals.indexOf(navigatedMeal) + 1
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You should calculate the index of `currentMeal` and `navigatedMeal` once at the very beginning.

**2)** You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to return subarray of an array and It doesn't affect the original data set.

```js
const meals = ["morning", "afternoon", "evening", "night", "midnight"];

const currentMeal = "afternoon";
const navigatedMeal = "midnight";

const currentMealIndex = meals.indexOf(currentMeal);
const navigatedMealIndex = meals.indexOf(navigatedMeal);
const skippedMealsBy = navigatedMealIndex - currentMealIndex;

if (skippedMealsBy > 1) {
  const skippedMealsArray = meals.slice(currentMealIndex + 1, navigatedMealIndex + 1);
  console.log(skippedMealsArray);
}
```